# Understanding how retrieving non-existing attributes with EL and JSP expression works. Inconsistency with Head First

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, el, scriptlet

There are two ways I can retrieve an attribute inside my JSP. Using `JSP expressions` or `EL`. What would happens if given attribute doesn't exist in those two cases? Let's try it (*user* doesn't exist):

```
<html><body>

--- <br>
<%=application.getAttribute("user") %>
<br>
--- <br>
${applicationScope.user}
<br>
---

</body></html>
```

OUTPUT:

```
 --- 
 null 
 --- 

 ---
```

What I understood from this is that **EL gives empty space**, while **JSP expression gives NULL**. But while reading Head First JSP and Servlets, I came across totally different explanation as stated in this screenshot.
[image]

It says that they **both give empty space**, which as I showed isn't correct. Can someone guess what the case here is? I doubt they made such a mistake in well known book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Books are written by people, and people make mistakes. You are correct in catching that. It should print null in the second example.

As a matter of fact, there are [a bunch of other errors](https://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=9780596516680) in the book. In this case, the errata shows this:

[image]